# Why can't Java generic be used for static methods?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, static

As the title states, why can't Java generics be used for static methods?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<T>` is the generic type of the class. You cannot refer to it from a `static` context, since each **instance** of the class may have a different `T` (similar to why you can't reference instance members from `static` methods). You could, however, give the method itself a generic type:

```
public static <S> S test (S s) {
    // code...
}
```